# Getting hold of a variable in complex compound term in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a Prolog sentence parser that returns a sentence (passed into it as a list) split into two parts - a `Noun_Phrase` and a `Verb_Phrase`. See example below:

```
sentence(Sentence, sentence(np(Noun_Phrase), vp(Verb_Phrase))) :- 
        np(Sentence, Noun_Phrase, Remainder),  
        vp(Remainder, Verb_Phrase).
```

Now I want to take the `Noun_Phrase` and `Verb_Phrase` and pass them into another Prolog predicate, but first **I want to extract the first term from the** `Verb_Phrase` (which should always be a verb) into a variable and the rest of the `Verb_Phrase` into another one and pass them separately into the next predicate.

I thought about using unification for this and I have tried:

```
sentence(Sentence, sentence(np(Noun_Phrase), vp(Verb_Phrase))),
     [Head|Tail] = Verb_Phrase, 
     next_predicate(_, Noun_Phrase, Head, Tail, _).
```

But I am getting *ERROR: Out of local stack exception* every time. I think this has something to do with the Verb_Phrase not really being a list. This is a possible isntance of Verb_Phrase:

```
VP = vp(vp(verb(making), adj(quick), np2(noun(improvements))))
```

How could I get the `verb(X)` as variable Verb and the rest of the term as varaible Rest out of such compound term in Prolog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `=../2` like:

```
 Verb_Phrase=..[Verb|Rest_Term_list].
```

Example:

```
?- noun(improvements)=..[Verb|Rest_Term_list].
Verb = noun,
Rest_Term_list = [improvements].
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do something very similar to what I needed.