# Predicate for removing certain terms from compound term in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I would like to write a Prolog predicate that takes in a compound term as its argument and outputs this compound term with some of the nested terms removed. For example, let's say that I have a compound term:

```
outer_term(level_one(level_two_a(X), level_two_b(Y)), level_one(level_two_b(Z))).
```

And I would like to write a predicate `extract_terms/2` which would take this term and returned it without occurences of `level_two_a/1`.

```
extract_terms(Term, ExtractedTerm) :-
       *** Prolog Magic ***.
```

Is there a built-in (or semi-built-in) way to do this in Prolog? If not, how would I go about doing this? One way that occurs to me would be to use `=../2` operator to convert the Term into a list and then somehow use some built-in predicate like `subtract/3` to get rid of the predicates that I want. The trouble I have is making this work with list that has nested terms as its items.

I would appreciate any ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a general guideline:

Everything that *can* be expressed by pattern matching *should* be expressed by pattern matching.

You have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836735/getting-hold-of-a-variable-in-complex-compound-term-in-prolog) previously, although it was a bit simpler. Still, let us consider the simpler case first: You said a possible instance of a *verb phrase* would be:

```
VP = vp(vp(verb(making), adj(quick), np2(noun(improvements))))
```

and you want to extract the *verb*. Well, the simplest approach is to use **pattern matching**, or more generally, *unification*, like this:

```
?- VP = vp(vp(verb(making), adj(quick), np2(noun(improvements)))),
   VP = vp(vp(Verb, _, _)).
```

This yields:

```
Verb = verb(making).
```

Thus, we have successfully "extracted" `verb(making)` from such a phrase by virtue of unification.

Now to the slightly more complex task you are considering in this question: At this point, you may wonder whether you have chosen a good *representation* of your data. Frequent use or even the very necessity of `(=..)/2` typically indicates a problem with your representation, since it may mean that you have lost track or control of the possible shapes of your data.

In this concrete case, you state as an example:

```
outer_term(level_one(level_two_a(X), level_two_b(Y)), level_one(level_two_b(Z))).
```

and you want to remove occurrences of `level_two_a`. You can now of course begin to mess with `(=..)/2`, which requires a conversion of such terms to *lists*, then some reasoning on these lists, and a second conversion from lists back to such structures. That's not how we want to work with our data. In addition to other drawbacks, it would *preclude* more general usage patterns that we expect from relations.

Instead, let us **fix the data representation** so that we can *cleanly* distinguish the different cases. For example, instead of "hardcoding" the very parameter we need to distinguish the cases *inside* of a functor, let us make the distinction *explicit*: We want to be able to distinguish, by **pattern matching**, level 1 from level 2.

So, the following representation suggests itself:

```
outer_term([level(1, [level(2, X),
                      level(2, Y)]),
            level(1, [level(2, Z)])]).
```

This may need some additional attributes, such as `a` and `b`, and I leave extending this representation to represent such attributes as an easy exercise. The general idea should be clear though: We have thus achieved a *uniform* representation about which we can easily reason *symbolically*.

It is now easy to describe the *relation* between a (potentially nested) list of such levels and the levels *without* the "level 2" elements:

```
without_level_2(Ls0, Ls) :-
        phrase(no_level_2(Ls0), Ls).

no_level_2([]) --> [].
no_level_2([L|Ls]) -->
        no_level_2_(L),
        no_level_2(Ls).

no_level_2_(level(2,_))   --> [].
no_level_2_(level(L,Ls0)) --> [level(L,Ls)],
        { dif(L, 2),
          without_level_2(Ls0, Ls) }.
```

See [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for more information about this formalism.

Sample query:

```
?- outer_term(Ts0),
   without_level_2(Ts0, Ts).
```

Yielding:

```
Ts = [level(1, []), level(1, [])] .
```

Note that to truly benefit from this representation, you need to obtain it in the first place by using or generating terms of such shapes. Once you have this ensured, you can conveniently stick to pattern matching to distinguish the cases. Among the main benefits of this approach we find *convenience*, *performance* and *generality*. For example, we can use the DCG shown above not only to *extract* but also to *generate* terms of this form:

```
?- length(Ls0, _), without_level_2(Ls0, Ls).
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = [level(2, _56)],
Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [level(_130, [])],
dif(_130, 2) ;
Ls0 = [level(_150, [level(2, _164)])],
Ls = [level(_150, [])],
dif(_150, 2) .
```

This is truly a *relation*, usable in all directions. For this reason, I have *avoided* imperative names like "extract", "remove" etc. in the predicate name, because these always suggest a particular *direction* of use, not doing justice to the generality of the predicate.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, it was really enlightening reading! As for pattern matching, I do this where possible (where I can assume the structure of incoming data). As for the second part of your answer, I really like the idea of rebuilding the data representation in the way that you suggest and use this to my benefit in actually manipulating the data. The main problem with this would be the nature of the data as I am not able to change representation of data that I am getting and therefore unable of structuring it differently. The other problem would be my level of expertise in Prolog.

Comment: Sometimes you are not in control, initially, of the exact layout of the data. But once you are in control, I recommend you always first *convert* the data to a clean representation, so that subsequent reasoning is easier. In this conversion step, you can for example use `(=..)/2`. I recommend you first focus on this conversion (and ask a separate question about it if you need any help). Start with a predicate like `input_clean/2`, relating the input to a *cleaner* representation. Once the data is converted to a uniform structure, you can much more easily reason about it.

Comment: I will try and abide by your suggestions. Thank you again for responding so quickly and extensively, it is much appreciated.

Comment: did you say "as an easy exercise" so that I would feel like an idiot when it turns out to be an impossible exercise for me ?

Comment: No haha, or rather only if you want to appeal to the rule *ex falso quodlibet*: I don't think this is impossible for you!